# Angular *ngIf memory usage

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Is my observation correct that even though *ngIf host element is not in the DOM it is in the memory/heap.
So it is creating the host element but do not attach it to the DOM.

I am on it because I have a huge list. Inside each list element are some *ngIfs. I see a lot of detached nodes and memory usage. When I remove not used *ngIfs then my memory and detached nodes counter is much smaller.

If it like that what is the best way to handle it?
I need to decide during the run time if the element will have input, text, time-picker field etc.

Thanks.

As a soulution, if someone has same problem:
[GitHub- ngIf keeps node in memory](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27263#issuecomment-531462901)

Answer (score 3):

I think you got it wrong, we can see in angular.io docs:

[NgIf case study](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngif-case-study):

> When the condition is false, NgIf removes its host element from the DOM, detaches it from DOM events (the attachments that it made), detaches the component from Angular change detection, and destroys it. **The component and DOM nodes can be garbage-collected and free up memory**.

[Why remove rather than hide?](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#why-remove-rather-than-hide):

> Although invisible, the component—and all of its descendant
>   components—tie up resources. The performance and memory burden can be
>   substantial, responsiveness can degrade, and the user sees nothing.

Comment: I have read the documentation and saw it. But it is not what I see during my test. So I searched it and read in some blog that it is not like that. That Angular keep it in memory. So it can fast attch it to the DOM when it needed. That is why I am unsure.

Comment: Why don't u look in angular github repository (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues) for an issue of this kind, and if there is none, ask them yourself and see what the angular team themselves has to say, rather than a 'post man'

Comment: Maybe beacause of that: Do not open issues for general support questions as we want to keep GitHub issues for bug reports and feature requests. You've got much better chances of getting your question answered on Stack Overflow where the questions should be tagged with tag angular.

Comment: @user5931608 If you think there's a memory leak, that sounds like grounds for a bug report.

Comment: @user5931608 Did you report it? If yes, what did the Chrome team say?

Comment: @phng I updated my question. Look at the github issue. My solution was to reduce ngIfs.